# WIN API.Рисование мышью .мышь оставляет след на экране при нажатой левой кнопки мыши.

Tags: c++, winapi

не рисует. подскажите, в чем ошибка

```
struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int _x, int _y) :x(_x), y(_y) {}
};

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HDC hDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static int x, y;
    static BOOL bTracking=FALSE ;
    static vector<Point> curve;
    static vector<vector<Point>> curves;    
    vector <Point>::iterator it;
    switch(uMsg){
    case WM_CREATE:
        hDC = GetDC(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        bTracking = TRUE;
        x = LOWORD(lParam);
        y = HIWORD(wParam);
        MoveToEx(hDC, x, y, NULL);
        curve.push_back(Point(x, y));
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        if (bTracking) { bTracking = FALSE; 
        curves.push_back(curve);
        curve.clear();
        }
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        if (bTracking) {
            x = LOWORD(lParam);
            y = HIWORD(wParam);
            //SelectObject(hDC, pen);
            LineTo(hDC, x, y);
            curve.push_back(Point(x, y));
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < curves.size(); ++i) {
            it = curves[i].begin();
            //SelectObject(hDC, pen);
            MoveToEx(hDC, it->x, it->y, NULL);
            for (++it; it != curves[i].end();) LineTo(hDC, it->x, it->y);
        }
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return (DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Ошибка во взятии координат
    x = LOWORD(lParam);
    y = HIWORD(**lParam**);

2) Не рассчитывать на рисование вне BeginPaint/EndPaint - hDC там вовсе не обязан быть валидным и т.д. При необходимости перерисовки делать, например, invalidaterect